# jquery validation with ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation and i need to validate an email.

I use

```
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: 
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
})
```

SO FAR so good. The problem is that i need to make an ajax call to verify if given email already exist.If exist display message "This email already exits.Please selecte other".

Can anyone help me implement this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
remote: "/some/remote/path"
```

That path will be passed the value of the field in a $_GET.
so.. what actually gets called in your case would be:

```
/some/remote/path?email=someemailuriencoded
```

Have the server side code return just the text true or false.

Then the corresponding message also named remote.

```
remote: "The corresponding email already exists"
```

My code for something similar:

```
$("#password_reset").validate({
  rules: { 
    email: { required: true, email: true, minlength: 6, remote: "/ajax/password/check_email" }
  }, 
  messages: { 
    email: { required: "Please enter a valid email address", minlength: "Please enter a valid email address", email: "Please enter a valid email address", remote: "This email is not registered" }
  }, 
  onkeyup: false,
  onblur: true
});
```

The corresponding server side code in php:

```
$email_exists = $db->prows('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1', 's' , $_GET['email'] );
if ( $email_exists ) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; }
exit;
```

Of course that's using my database abstraction stuff, but you get it.

Comment: Thank Daren. I will test drive it, i think thats it

Comment: how can i add message only for remote...or how can i 'do-something' onsuccess

Comment: You just saved me hours of time. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Well, this works for me...

```
 $('[id$=txtEmail]').rules("add", { required: true, email: true,
         remote:function(){
              var checkit={
                  type: "POST",
                  url:  WebServicePathComplete+"VerifyEmail",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: "{'email':'" +$('[id$=txtEmail]').val() + "'}"
              };
              return checkit;
         }
  });
```

note that I have a input with the id 'txtMail'

Answer (score 0):

Whats your server language? PHP or ASP?

This is the jQuery part:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourWebserviceOrWhatEver",
    data: "{'Email':'your@ema.il'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      if(msg.EmailExists){
        //Email exists
        alert("This email already exists. Please select other");
      }
      else {
       //Email doesn't exist yet
       doSomething();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: he's using validate, which has the ajax built in.

Comment: Think the author meant a use of the jQuery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. Not just an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i want to tell you that if you are using post method in ajax then dont pass email in url.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URLROOT + '/register/check/';
        data: {email:email};
         success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'exist') {
              return false;
             } else {
             return true;
             }
          }
      });`
```

after that you remove parameter from controller's function.

```
`public function check(l) {
  if($this->userModel->findUserByEmail($_POST['email'])==true)) {
   return 'exist';
  }
  return 'false';
 }`
```

Try with this.