# Validating multiple fields in an MVC form using a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have two fields in my MVC form (fieldA and fieldB). There's a requirement that fieldA and fieldB's inputs cannot exist in the database already, I.E.:

- fieldA has a value of x and fieldB has a value of y. The database has a record/row where fieldA has a value of x and fieldB has a value of y, so this input form is invalid.
- Following the last example, fieldA has a value of x, but fieldB has a value of z. There is no record/row in the database where fieldA = x AND fieldB = z, so the input form is valid.

I'm assuming I have to create a new ValidationAttribute from here, but I'm completely new to MVC and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: the only way I can think of to achieve this is to do an ajax call and doing the validation server side.  something like they do here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564711/jquery-validation-with-ajax-call

Comment: Do you need client side validation?

Comment: For the client side validation, you can use a `[Remote]` attribute (passing the second value using the `AdditionalFields` property. [Refer How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging around, I stumbled upon this link: http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/05/validating-dependent-fields-in-asp-net-mvc

I don't have an elegant-looking solution, but I basically looked at the majority of IsValid and modified it to do a database query, and it seems to work. It's not as efficient as Remote but it gets the job done.