# How to validate if an email is unique is or not using jQuery.validate and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am working with a Registration form, for validation process i am using jQuery.validate();

Now i need to validate an email if it is unique in the system or not, using ajax.

Any way to do this using jQuery.validate() ?

Comment: See `remote` method:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remote` option with your validation rule. This question is already answered, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564724/2738828)

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that contains only a link.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to do that. I recently got Flag Posts privilege.

Comment: That makes no difference.  Posting an answer as a workaround for not enough reputation is considered as bypassing the rules.